# How to setup an asp.net core 2.1 web api with angular 7 universal

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli, asp.net-core-webapi, server-side-rendering

As of now, there is no up to date guide/article that explains how to setup a Asp.NET Core 2.1 web api project with Angular 7 Universal (server side rendering)

I have seen multiple portions code, examples and explanations scattered around the internet, but the pieces don't always fit together.

What are the main steps and the recommendations (best practices if possible) to follow in order to start a clean project with the specified requirements? (angular 7 universal, asp.net core 2.1 web api)

Comment: Can you try the following walkthrough and see if it works? Beware, after starting the debugging, you must be patient and wait for the angular dist/server folder to appear. Then you can F5 the browser. https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-6df7adacbdaa